# Kendo Grid PopUp Custom edit buttons?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

Create and Edit with the Kendo Grid popup Can I use a different template?

Create default, Editor a different template. So, Custom command button click will do. Then I set my future fields. Is it possible?

Create button is different, I want to show different areas of the edit buttons.

I know a little English :/

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean and what you want. But if you want to use a different template for create and edit operation. I guess You can build a button in the toolbar template. then attach a kendo window (which contains the Create template) to the button click event. You might probably need to do ajax post when submitting the data

Comment: I mean exactly that. Thanks Roti!